# Change the Public IP Address of Azure VPN Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I have created a Virtual Network Gateway in Azure with a particular Private IP Address. Now customer want me to change the Private IP Address to a particular IP. But i am not getting any option to do so. Could anybody help me on how to change the Public IP Address of a Virtual Network Gateway in Azure post creation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear : do you want to change private IP address (as stated at the beginning), or the public one ?

Anyway, from what I remember :

1. You can't choose private IP address, it is taken from the subnet where you created it
2. To change public IP address, the connection must be stopped, then, from Azure Portal, access to the Public IP Address resource associated, and you'll be able to manage it as any other Public IP Address resource.